# Why doesn't the Taylor expansion at 0 around $ e^{-1/x^2} $ converge to the function itself?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I know that if you take the Taylor expansion at $x = 0$ of $e^{-1/x^2}$, you get $f(x) = 0$. However, I was wondering if a rigorous proof could be shown of why the Taylor expansion and the actual function differ at every point (other than 0) in this case. I was thinking of using the Lagrange Remainder:
$$
R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n)}(z)x^n}{n!}
$$
where $z \in (0, x)$ for any $x$. I tried to show why $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} R_n(x) \neq 0$ but I was running into trouble. Specifically, it seems like the $n!$ term grows faster than the top, alongside the fact it was quite hard to characterize the value of $f^{(n)}(z)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The absolute value of $f^{(n)}(z)$ will be dominated by the supremum of $g(z)=e^{-1/z^2}2^nz^{-3n}$, which is achieved by $g(2/\sqrt{3n})=(Cn^{3/2})^n=h(n)$ when $n$ is large enough, with $C=e^{-3/4}3\sqrt{3}/4$. The correct bound of $R_n$ is thus $\approx h(n)x^n/n!$, which blows up as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You just showed that $f$ is bounded by a function that blows up as n gets large. In fact, the remainder term is just f itself.

Comment: @Matematleta Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Maclaurin polynomial is zero for each integer $n$, the remainder term is just $f$ itself, and since this does not vanish for $x\neq 0,\ f$ is not represented by a Taylor series ar $x=0.$

Comment: Ah, that's actually quite straightforward. I feel kinda stupid now :/

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor expansion *does converge* - to the function that's everywhere $0$. For every $n$ the remainder term at $x$ (the error in the Taylor expansion) is $\exp(-1/x^2)$, the value of the function you started with.

Comment: I'm wondering why the Taylor expansion doesn't converge to the actual function itself. I think what I'm looking for is _why_ the remainder term is nonzero.

Comment: The remainder term is nonzero because the error will always exist.

Comment: The remainder term is (by definition) the difference between the $n$th degree Taylor polynomial and the function. Since that polynomial is identically $0$, the remainder term is the value of the function. You could use that fact to work out what the value of $z$ is in the Lagrange formula for the remainder.

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve the -1

Comment: I agree with @CalvinKhor .